# Active Gizmo show all even when axis locked

Tags: versions

Just a general question, which has puzzled me. The 2.81 active gizmo whether in Move, Rotate or Scale always shows everything. Previously it would only show the axis which were unlocked. When locking, as in the photo, only the Z arrow would appear in previous versions.
Am I missing something, can this be changed?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have changed the orientation for the gizmo. Locking the global X,Y-axes will cause the X,Y-axes to be hidden in the gizmo only if the gizmo is set to global or default orientation.

The setting for this is found in the top left of your screen. Do not confuse the *Gizmo Orientation* with *Transform Orientation*. The transform orientation (middle of screen) is used as the when you use a hotkey such as <kbd>G</kbd> to edit an object.

[image]
[image]